# Google Code Jam Minimum Scalar Product

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was solving a problem from Google Code Jam and I am not able to solve the problem: http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/32016/dashboard#s=p0 (Minimum Scalar Product, Problem A 2008)

The strategy I used was:

1. Accept `v1` and `v2` from the user
2. Sort both `v1` and `v2`
3. Reverse `v2` i.e. sort `v2` in descending order
4. Multiply straight-out corresponding `v1[i] * v2[i]` and store the result in `product`
5. Sum up all such products and print the answer

I did some research and indeed it appears that's the only permutation that's possible to obtain. However, my code does not produce the correct output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int T;
    int cases;
    FILE *fin  = fopen ("A-small-practice.in", "r"); // open input file
    FILE *fout = fopen ("output.out", "w");

    fscanf(fin, "%d", &T);
    for(cases = 1; cases <= T; cases++)
    {
        int v1[1000], v2[1000];
        int i,j; int n;
        int product =0;
        fscanf(fin, "%d", &n);

        for(i=0; i < n; i++)
        {            
            fscanf(fin, "%d",&v1[i]);
            fscanf(fin, "%d", &v2[i]);            
        }

        sort(v1,v1+n);
        sort(v2,v2+n);
        reverse(v1, v1+n);

        int k;
        for(k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {                        
            product += v1[k] * v2[k];            
        }
        fprintf(fout, "Case #%d: %d\n", cases, product);
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of troubleshooting, I found that the problem was in the way input was taken, as I had used only one loop for both v1 & v2:

```
for(i=0; i < n; i++)
    {            
        fscanf(fin, "%d",&v1[i]);
        fscanf(fin, "%d", &v2[i]);            
    }
```

And it should have been done this way:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
fscanf(fin, "%d",&v1[i]);
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
fscanf(fin, "%d", &v2[i]);
```

Thank you lukas1994 and pkacprzak

Answer (score 2):

You should use `long long`.
This worked for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
long long T,n,v1[1000],v2[1000];
cin >> T;
for (int t = 1; t <= T; t++) {
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> v1[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> v2[i];
    sort(v1,v1+n);
    sort(v2,v2+n);
    long long p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        p += v1[i]*v2[n-i-1];
    cout << "Case #" << t << ": " << p << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

using std::vector;

long long min_dot_product(size_t n, vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
    long long result = 0;
    if (n != 0)
    {
        std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
        std::sort(b.begin(), b.end());
        std::reverse(a.begin(), a.end());

        /*for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result += a[i] * b[n - 1 - i];
        }*/

        result = std::inner_product(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 0);

    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    size_t n;
    std::cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n), b(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> b[i];
    }
    std::cout << min_dot_product(n, a, b) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a specific case to be considered.

When one vector is all negative and the other all positive, the algorithm does not produce the minimum result.

```
if x = [-1,-2] and x = [1,2]
```

the minimum according to the algorithm output is :

```
(-1*2) + (-2*1) = -4
```

However, if you instead use x1y1 + x2y2... xnyn for this case you get:

```
(-1 * 1) + ( -2*2) = -1-4 = -5
```

Comment: This is not really an answer, but a comment (though I understand using the answer box to be readable).  However, even accepting it as such, it is not clear exactly which answer you are commenting on, or how your would improve it.

Comment: @snoeyink this answer is wrong , the algorithm do give the right answer, 
In your example you have sorted the -ve numbers wrongly.